# Include link in Facebook attachment(stream)

Tags: facebook

How can I include links in facebook attachment (stream)?
It shows the <a> tag as plain text.

Also, what is the use of properties?

properties: An array of key/value pairs that provide more information about the post. The properties array can contain plain text and links only. To include a link, the value of the property should be a dictionary with 'text' and 'href' attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new post is added to the forum thread I mention:
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=42985

this 'bug' has already been reported to facebook. you can vote on it here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7357

Answer (score 1):

If your attachment has an **href** key, it will be formatted as a hyperlink. For example:

```
{'media':
  [{'type': 'image',
    'src':  'http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/funny-pictures-kitten-finished-his-milk-and-wants-a-cookie.jpg', 
    'href': 'http://icanhascheezburger.com/2009/03/30/funny-pictures-awlll-gone-cookie-now/'}, 
   {'type': 'image',
    'src':  'http://photos.icanhascheezburger.com/completestore/2009/1/18/128768048603560273.jpg', 
    'href': 'http://ihasahotdog.com/upcoming/?pid=20869'}]}
```

That will load two images, each of which is wrapped in a hyperlink.